# How to recover data from journal file?

Tags: sqlite

I have a database and its journal. I want to recover data from a deleted entry. The journal should contain both addition of the data to the DB and removal from it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html),

> when a writer is ready to commit its changes, it executes the following steps:
>   […]
>   6. Delete the journal file. (Or if the PRAGMA journal_mode is TRUNCATE or PERSIST, truncate the journal file or zero the header of the journal file, respectively.)

It is the destruction of the journal that signals that the transaction was committed. (Valid data in the journal would imply that the transaction was *not* committed completely, and that it needs to be rolled back.)

It is not possible to recover deleted data from the journal.

Comment: Thanks , due to size of the journal 25% of db size , I thought that it like H2 journal where all statements are stored.